# Rickshaw: Changing colors of X-Axis Labels

Tags: css, svg, graph, rickshaw

By default the labels are all a dark gray, I've tried to override them using CSS multiple ways.

How do I change the label's color on render?
Or how do I change the color in the SVG output?

I've looked everywhere and have found similar titles but different meanings. Love how manipulatable this graph is, but the label text color is a must for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the way to do it. Gotta use JS to overwrite the attributes.

After the graph.render() function use these:

```
$('.x_ticks_d3 text').css('opacity', '1.0');//fix text opacity
$('#x_axis text').css('fill', 'white');//text color
$('.x_ticks_d3 .tick').css('stroke-width', '0px');//text smoothing
$('#x_axis path').css('opacity', '0');//remove line or
$('#x_axis path').css('stroke', 'white');//change line color
```

This got everything to be white for me, and was able to remove the lines also.